# Android 4.1 SDK : Reading content of file at URL results in android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, url

I found the method to read text response from URL here on SO and the code compiles fine but results in the app crashing when the thread is started:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
             URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.10/test.php");
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
             String line = null;
             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  //do stuff
             }
             in.close();
          }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
           }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I did further search, an answer on SO suggest adding permission to the manifest file like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Yet I am still getting the same result:

```
06-21 15:48:24.597    2362-2362/?                              E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
    at com.smilegrp.ksone.MainActivity$2$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    at com.smilegrp.ksone.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why is this? I have coded in iOS before and I find Google's official documentation rather confusing and difficult to follow compared to Apple's. :/

Comment: use asynch task to call url

Comment: and the reason for the down vote is?

Comment: This is a well-known issue you will get tons of question related to this query!!! [check it out](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=NetworkOnMainThreadException&oq=NetworkOnMainThreadException&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.2695397.3292074.0.3292405.53.20.0.0.0.5.316.2125.0j11j1j1.13.0...0.7.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.8N1R8vQXtJA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bmk&fp=cb0f4f4c47aa750f&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=955)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception means that you are performing network operation on the `UI Thread`. Since you  are running it inside a `Thread` be sure to call `start()` instead of `run()` on the `Thread`'s instance

Answer (score 0):

The error is: NetworkOnMainThreadException. Which means that you can't do network things on your mainthread. 
Create an Asynctask, and do your network stuff in the doInBackground method of the Asynctask.

Comment: how come other people arent having any trouble with this.

Comment: Since the new Android (4.0), you have to do network things on a background thread. You don't want your whole app to hang just because you cant reach a server :)

Comment: @harmjanr he is using a thread ... so either he is using it wrong(blackbelt's answer) or exception is not from this code ..

Comment: @Selvin oh, didn't see that :( But still, it;s more useful to use Asynctasks, since you have more options than creating a new Runnable (OnPreExecute, OnPostExecute)..